# How to add multiple key and value for search object array

Tags: javascript

I have function code for search data in array, it goes well *but* in one key and one value. what I want is an array search with multiple key and value, ​​that work like query `and` in sql.

**My question:** How to add multiple key and value in my function code?

Array Data:

```
[{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "John",
    "addres": {
      "code": 1,
      "status": 1
    }
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Jery",
    "addres": {
      "code": 2,
      "status": 1
    }
  }
]
```

My Function code:

```
function where(prop, value) {
  var filtered = [], checkStatus = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    var obj = data[i];
    for (var key in obj) {
      var item = obj[key];
      if (typeof(obj[key] == "object")) {
        if (item[prop] == value) {
          checkStatus = 1;
          filtered.push(obj);
        }
        if (typeof(value) == "string") {
          if (item[prop] != undefined
            && item[prop].toLowerCase().includes(value.toLowerCase())) {
            checkStatus = 1;
            filtered.push(obj);
          }
        }
      }
    }
    if (checkStatus == 0 && obj[prop] != undefined) {
      if (obj[prop] == value) {
        filtered.push(obj);
      }
      if (typeof(obj[prop]) == 'string') {
        if (obj[prop] != undefined
          && obj[prop].toLowerCase().includes(value.toLowerCase())) {
          filtered.push(obj);
        }
      }
    }
  }
  return filtered;
}
```

Its work when `where('status',1)` but what i want `where(['id','status'],[2,1])`

Comment: Instead of `where(['id','status'],[2,1])`, I suggest using ab object. `where({'id':1,  'status':'2' })`

Comment: sorry I can't do that because I have 2 parameters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry everyone, I tried and was successful

```js
function where(value) {
  var result = data.filter(function(o) {
    return Object.keys(value).every(function(p) {
      if (typeof(o[p]) == 'object') {
        return Object.keys(value[p]).some(function(opo) {
          if (typeof(value[p][opo]) == 'string') {
            return o[p][opo].toLowerCase().includes(value[p][opo].toLowerCase());
          } else {
            return o[p][opo] == value[p][opo];
          }
        });
      } else if (typeof(o[p]) == 'string') {
        return o[p].toLowerCase().includes(value[p].toLowerCase());
      } else {
        return o[p] == value[p];
      }
    });
  });
  return result;
}
```

Thank you for giving me advice on using object, for calling `where({id:2,addres:{status:1}})`